# What are the "CUPS" credentials when trying to add a printer via CUPS web interface?

Tags: software-installation, usb, usb-device, printer

I've supposedly installed the driver for a printer I want to start using on my Linux system (never mind exactly how). Now, I visit http://localhost:631/ to access the CUPS interface. This works, but it won't let me add a printer. When I try to do that, I get a prompt asking for credentials, and a message system saying something like "Remote system says CUPS". So, it seems like I need to enter credentials for a CUPS user? ... but I don't have such a user. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Make sure your printer is connected (e.g. via USB)
2. Ensure your own user and/or the root user are members of the lp group, e.g.:

   ```
   gpasswd -a my_account lp ; gpasswd -a my_user lp
   ```
3. Enter the credentials of your member-of-lp username and password

That should do it. Hopefully, you should see your printer already having been discovered.

(Tested with Devuan 3 Beowulf ~= Debian 10 Buster.)